# Fragment transition with shared imageview. Wrong animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have MainActivity which show two fragment with shared image.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void showPhoto(View sharedView, String sharedName) {
    Fragment listFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
    Fragment detailFragment = new SecondFragment();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        listFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
        listFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this)
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));
        detailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());

        detailFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this)
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.addSharedElement(sharedView, sharedName);
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, detailFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("viewer");
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

First fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_small);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showPhoto(image, "name");
        }
    });
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image, "name");
    return view;
}
```

Fist fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:transitionName="name"
    android:id="@+id/image_small"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_big);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image, "name");
    return view;
}
```

Second fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_big"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:transitionName="name"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

And I have next animation:
https://youtu.be/pRYHC59sSL8

But I want to make animation like this: 
https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.webm

What I am doing wrong?

Phone with Android 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showPhoto(View sharedView, String sharedName) {
   Fragment listFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
   Fragment detailFragment = new SecondFragment();
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         listFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
         listFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this)
            .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));
         detailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));

         detailFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this)
            .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));
}

   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaction.addSharedElement(sharedView, sharedName);
   transaction.replace(R.id.frame, detailFragment);
   transaction.addToBackStack("viewer");
   transaction.commit();
```

}

Comment: `sharedView` is shared element from first fragment.  What I should to do with mProductImage?

Comment: I tried replace `new ChangeImageTransform()` with inflating it from resource. But effect was same.

Comment: mProductImage means the ImagView which you want to shared between two Fragment.

Comment: In my case it named `sharedView`. I pass it from first fragment: `((MainActivity) getActivity()).showPhoto(image, "name");`